# Handle attachment in symplectic category

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, handle-decomposition

It is known that for an exact symplectic manifold $(M,\omega_M)$ with a convex boundary $(\partial M,\theta_M)$, where $d\theta_M=\omega_M$ (usually called a Liouville domain), one can attachment to it a $k$-handle $H_k$, so that the resulting manifold $M\cup_S H_k$ still carries the structure of a Liouville domain. Here $S\subset\partial M$ is a $k-1$-dimensional isotropic sphere with respect to the contact form $\theta_M$ on the contact boundary $\partial M$. This is known as **Weinstein handle attachment**.

The question is can we generalize this handle attaching operation to more general symplectic manifolds with boundary? For example, consider the total space of a symplectic vector bundle $E\rightarrow B$ over a symplectic manifold $(B,\omega_B)$, take the ball bundle of $E$ we get a symplectic manifold with boundary $M$. However, in general $\partial M$ is not a contact hypersurface with respect to the natural symplectic form on $M$. Then is there a version of handle attachment which is suitable for $M$?